# Запись матрицы в csv файл на java

Tags: java, файлы, csv, filewriter

Основное задание заключается в том, что б поменять местами столбики в csv файле. Я выгрузила их оттуда в матрицу, написала цикл с заменой столбиков, который по моим наблюдениям работает. Но теперь не могу записать почему то с помощью fileWriter-a ничего. Даже через цикл пробовала делать, записывает почему то просто слупленную вместе первую строку и все. Буду благодрана за помощь.

```
 import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File("c:");
        JFileChooser fileopen = new JFileChooser();
        int ret = fileopen.showDialog(null, "Открыть файл");
        if (ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            file = fileopen.getSelectedFile();
            String path = file.getAbsolutePath();
        }


        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        LinkedList<String[]> rows = new LinkedList<>();
        String dataRow;

        int i = 0;
        while ((dataRow = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            rows.addLast(dataRow.split(";"));
            i++;
        }

        String[][] csvMatrix = rows.toArray(new String[rows.size()][]);
        System.out.println(csvMatrix[2][0]);

        for (int j = 0; j < csvMatrix.length; j++) {
            String temp = csvMatrix[j][0];
            String temp1 = csvMatrix[j][1];

            csvMatrix[j][0] = temp1;
            csvMatrix[j][1] = temp;
        }

FileWriter fileWriter=new FileWriter(file);
      for(int j=0; j<csvMatrix.length; j++){
          for(int k=0; k<csvMatrix.length; k++){
              fileWriter.write(csvMatrix[j][k]);
              fileWriter.flush();
          }
      }
      fileWriter.close();

    }
}
```

Comment: А где, собственно, сама запись? И что значит "записывает бред"? Приведите пож. пример того, как Вы записываете и что в итоге получается в файле

Comment: Прошу прощения за неточности вопроса. Отредактировала

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не правильно выбираете элемент записи(см.  `for(int k=0; k<csvMatrix.length; k++){`).

У вас массив массивов. Получается что `csvMatrix[j]` - это тоже массив. И перебирать тоже надо его(а не `csvMatrix.length`).

также к выводу надо добавить разделитель элементов(`;`) и перенос стоки после отработки(`fileWriter.write("\n");`)

Также метод "сброса буффера в файл"(`fileWriter.flush();`) я бы добавил после записи строки

Измените ваш блок записи на:

```
    FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    for (int j = 0; j < csvMatrix.length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < csvMatrix[j].length; k++) {
            fileWriter.write(csvMatrix[j][k]+";");
        }
        fileWriter.write("\n");
        fileWriter.flush();
    }
    fileWriter.close();
```

**P.S:** если смущает `;` после последнего элемента, то измените блок записи с `fileWriter.write(csvMatrix[j][k]+";");` на

```
    fileWriter.write(csvMatrix[j][k]);
    if (k < csvMatrix[j].length - 1) {
       fileWriter.write(";");
    }
```